# FFMPEG for Android - missing alsa format

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, alsa

@rowntreerob  has an android-ffmpeg implementation that build successfully using the default file settings.
 When you remove disble-avdevice and disbale-devices from the configure_ffmpeg script, ndk-build fails. The following is the error message:

> CP ffmpeg 
>      STRIP ffmpeg
>      ~/android-ffmpeg/Project/jni
>  ~/android-ffmpeg/Project/jni
>     ~/android-ffmpeg/Project/jni
>      jasongipsyblues@android-master:~/android-ffmpeg/Project/jni$ ndk-build
>      Compile thumb  : ffmpeg <= ffmpeg.c 
>      Compile thumb  : ffmpeg <= cmdutils.c
>      Executable     : ffmpeg
>      /home/jasongipsyblues/android-ffmpeg/Project/obj/local/armeabi-      >v7a/objs/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.o: In function `main':
>
> /home/jasongipsyblues/android-ffmpeg/Project/jni/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.c:6130: undefined   >reference to `avdevice_register_all'
>
> /home/jasongipsyblues/android-ffmpeg/Project/obj/local/armeabi- >v7a/objs/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/cmdutils.o: In function `print_all_libs_info':
>
> /home/jasongipsyblues/android-ffmpeg/Project/jni/ffmpeg/cmdutils.c:639: undefined >reference to `avdevice_configuration'
>
> /home/jasongipsyblues/android-ffmpeg/Project/jni/ffmpeg/cmdutils.c:639: undefined >reference to `avdevice_version'
>   
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make: **** [/home/jasongipsyblues/android-ffmpeg/Project/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/ffmpeg] >Error 1

Please pardon my poor formating skills, I still dont get the formating thing. It appears the deletion of the references is to avdevices is definitely  affecting the use of ndk-build.

All the alsa source files exist in the ffmpeg code. How does one build ffmpeg in such a way that alsa is included in the formats?

Comment: undefined >reference to `avdevice_register_all'  typically means you're not linking against libavdevice.a FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

I've built FFMPEG using this open source  http://code.google.com/p/dolphin-player/. You are getting libffmpeg.so and then using it in your project.

I don't know if alsa is included in it but it looks like it is very easy to find out from their configure script.

Comment: there is no provision for adding also in the configuration file.   May be I need to ask how to build ffmpeg for android so that alsa is included in the build. Theoretically one needs libasound to be present on a system to be able to build alsa into ffmpeg. BTW I am doing my tests on the ffmpeg binary not on the shared object. If you have successfully built ffmpeg for android, could you please check in your ffmpeg folder and test your binary for presence of alsa in the formats. ** ffmpeg - formats **should list alsa as one of the present formats. TIA